# Fast user Switching remains disabled

Tags: macos, user-account

Even when I unlock the *Fast User Switching* functionality, using an admin account, the menu remains disabled.

What could be causing this? And, how could I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean with *disabled*? Could you elaborate on that, or even, add a screenshot?

Comment: Disabled means the way it remains before you have clicked the lock icon in the bottom left to unlock admin account. Sorry i am not able to post a screenshot @Thecafremo

Comment: Have you * cough * got more than one user?

Comment: Yes ,Sir I do have more than one user on my system, thats why I ask what;s wrong with this. Can there be any script or any system files which has got deleted that has caused this ?